# How to retrieve ARN for domain through Amazon PHP SDK?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Is there a way to retrieve an ARN for a domain name through the API?  I'm trying to automatically pull the ARN to authenticate a from address for an email using Amazon SES.  The ARN should automatically be generated for the domain name that has been verified.

It seems that the PHP SDK doesn't have any methods that allow for this, but perhaps there is another way besides having to manually log into the IAM console and copy/paste each ARN each time a new domain is added?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, ARNs can be accessed through the IAM API.  The PHP SDK can use `getUser()`, but it needs to connect through IAM, not SES.

Here is the complete code that works for me -

```
require 'aws/aws-autoloader.php';
use Aws\Iam\IamClient;
use Guzzle\Service\Exception\CommandTransferException;

$iam = IamClient::factory(array(
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'credentials' => array(
    'key'    => 'ACCESS KEY',
    'secret' => 'SECRET KEY'
    )
));

$result = $iam->getUser(array(
    'UserName' => 'example.com',
));

print $result['User']['Arn'];
```